# Arithmetic Sequence in Harmonic Sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

If Harmonic Sequence

$$
H_n=\left\{ {1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{5},...} \right\}
$$

How can I find an arithmetic sequence using the above sequence?

Actually, I have found one by inspection.
$$
\left\{{\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{6}}\right\}\\
\text{It is an arithmetic sequence with common difference}=-\frac{1}{6}
$$
However, I have no idea on finding the other arithmetic sequence with more term.
Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that your example can be written over the common denominator 12 as
$$\frac{4}{12}, \frac{3}{12}, \frac{2}{12}.$$
This suggests starting with a (decreasing) arithmetic progression of natural numbers, then finding common denominator, and turning it into fractions.

This likely would give long progressions.

EDIT: Try the sequence $$\frac{n-k}{n!}$$ for $k=0,1,2...;$ for example $n=5$ gives $$\frac{1}{24},\frac{1}{30},\frac{1}{40},\frac{1}{60},\frac{1}{120}.$$

Comment: I am now able to find 6 term arithmetic progression with your hint of common divisor 12,but i still cannot find the higher term sequence

Comment: Oh,I know how to do it now.If the common divisor is 12,then we have 4 term sequence since 1,2,3,4 divides 12.If i choose a number k>n and 1,2,3,...,n divides k.Therefore we could get a n term sequence.Anyway,thanks for helping

Comment: Yes that works. See added remark under EDIT, using factorials.

Comment: Note that  you can use $\operatorname{lcm}\{1,2,3,\dots, n\}$ instead of $n!$.